# ContactsContract editor ignores email, phone intent data

Tags: android, android-intent, contactscontract

**(code segment revised - now working)**

According to the Android references
  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html
it should be possible to pass an array of emails and phone numbers to the contact editor.   Any one have success with this?

After a lot of research and experiments, nothing seems to work - it just ignores the parameters, as is evident by the editor opening with only the name field filled.  This is on a Nexus 7 running Android 4.2.1.  The Contacts app is version 4.2.1-533553.

Here's my code ("form" is declared and filled elsewhere):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction (Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setData (ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra (ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, form.name);

ArrayList<ContentValues> parcels = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

for (int i = 0;  i < form.phones.length;  i++)
{
  ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
  row.put (Data.MIMETYPE, CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
  row.put (CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, form.phones[i]);
  row.put (CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, form.phoneIds[i]);
  parcels.add (row);
}

for (int i = 0;  i < form.emails.length;  i++)
{
  ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
  row.put (Data.MIMETYPE, CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
  row.put (CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, form.emails[i]);
  row.put (CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, form.emailIds[i]);
  parcels.add (row);
}

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra (ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, parcels);
startActivityForResult (intent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_FULL_EDIT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add phones.add(row) and emails.add(row) each time you fill a row ?

Comment: Thanks - can't believe I missed that.  There was another problem, too.  Turns out you can only call putParcelableArrayListExtra one time; the solution is to put both the phones and emails into one "parcels".